# Explanation on the working out provided

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was again, working on my workbook and one of the questions and one part of the working out has me a bit confused.

The Question:

> In each case following, simplify $f(−x)$ and compare it with $f(x)$ and $−f(x)$ to determine whether the function is odd or even.
>
> a) $f(x)= \frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}$

The Working out:
$f(-x)= \frac{2^{-x}+2^{-(-x)}}{2}$

= $\frac{2^{-x}+2^x}{2}$

=$\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}$

Can someone explain how the minus moved from the first 2 to the other one?

Thanks.

Comment: Since addtion is commutative, $2^{-x}+2^x=2^x+2^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jose Carlos Santos said in the comments, $2^x+2^{-x} = 2^{-x} + 2^x $

This is known as the commutative property of addition. To write this symbolically,

$$a+b=b+a$$

Also, the function is even since $f(-x)=f(x)$